# Show that $ \ \ \large \lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}=+ \infty \ $

Tags: limits

Show that $ \ \  \large \lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}=+ \infty \ $ by using Taylor series  both in the numerator and denominator.

**Answer:**

$ \ \  \large \lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta} \\ = \lim_{ \theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\sin (2 \pi) +(\theta-2 \pi) \frac{\cos (2 \pi)}{1!}-(\theta-2 \pi)^2 \frac{\sin (2 \pi)}{2!}+.........}{1-\cos (2 \pi)+(\theta-2 \pi) \frac{\sin (2 \pi)}{1!}+(\theta-2 \pi)^2 \frac{\cos (2 \pi)}{2!}-........} \\ \\ = \lim_{ \theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{(\theta-2 \pi) \frac{\cos (2 \pi)}{1!}+...}{(\theta-2 \pi)^2 \frac{\cos (2 \pi)}{2!}-........}  \\ \\ = \lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\frac{\cos (2 \pi)}{1!}+.....}{(\theta-2 \pi) \frac{\cos (2 \pi)}{2!}+....} \\ = + \infty , \ \ because \ \ \theta > 2 \pi $

**Am I right?**

Comment: Seems fine for me.

Comment: The best way in these cases is to shift the point at which to calculate the limit at 0 by a change of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

We have
$$\sin (\theta)=\sin (\theta-2\pi)=$$

$$(\theta-2\pi)(1+\epsilon_1 (\theta)) $$

and
$$\cos (\theta)=\cos (\theta-2\pi)=$$
$$1-\frac {(\theta-2\pi)^2}{2}(1+\epsilon_2 (\theta))$$

Your function becomes

$$\frac {2 (1+\epsilon_1 (\theta))}{(\theta-2\pi)(1+\epsilon_2 (\theta))} $$

the limit is then $\frac {2}{0^+}=+\infty $.

Comment: using Taylor series

Comment: @yourmath That's what i did, near $2\pi $.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}=\\=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(2\pi+x)}{1-\cos (2\pi+x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos (x)}=\\=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos (x)}\frac{1}{x}=1\cdot2\cdot+ \infty=+ \infty $$

Answer (score 0):

Please note that $\lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}=\lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}}\cot(\frac{\theta}{2})=\cot(\pi)=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{\theta \to 2 \pi^{+}} \frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}=\\=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(2\pi+x)}{1-\cos (2\pi+x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos (x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos (x)}\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos (x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(x)(1+\cos x)}{\sin^2 (x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{(1+\cos x)}{\sin (x)}=2\cdot +\infty=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all observe that the limit is equivalent to the limit for $\theta \rightarrow 0^+$. At $0$ you have
$$\sin \theta = \theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\dots$$
$$\cos \theta = 1-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-\dots$$
Finally
$$\lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\dots}{1-1+\frac{\theta^2}{2!}-\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+\dots} = \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\dots}{\frac{\theta^2}{2!}-\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+\dots} = \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{(1-o(\theta))}{\theta\Big(\frac{1}{2!}-o(\theta)\Big)} = +\infty.$$
This is to simplify the expansions you get at $2\pi$.